# Contenteditable div with bold option

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, bold, italic

I want to make contenteditable div with **bold** and *italic* options to display content in another div on keyup with the same options.
I managed to display text, but not options. Please help

html:

```
<button onclick="document.execCommand('bold');">B</button>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('italic');">I</button>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable></div>
<div id="textarea-show"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
  $('#textarea-show').html($(this).text());
});
```

css:

```
#textarea { background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 450px;
}

  #textarea-show{font-size: 2rem;
  color:#666;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 450px;
}
```

example:https://jsfiddle.net/gqmLtct7/1/

Comment: 17anchi, please see my answer below. I hope that is what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add two classes, one let's say `bold` and the other `italic`, style them and toogle them on click of the buttons to activate/deactivate the bold/italic (You can run the code snippet below or you can also find the updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gqmLtct7/4/)):

**UPDATE**

After the OP's comment, as he wanted to add the bold and italic only to selected text, I've updated my answer a little bit.

The updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqmLtct7/8/).

And the updated code:

```js
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
  $('#textarea-show').html($(this).text());
});

$('#bold_btn').on('click', function() {
  //$('#textarea, #textarea-show').toggleClass('bold');
  document.execCommand('bold');
  var text = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;
  $('#textarea-show').html(text);
});
$('#italic_btn').on('click', function() {
  //$('#textarea, #textarea-show').toggleClass('italic');
  document.execCommand('italic');
  var text = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;
  $('#textarea-show').html(text);
});
```

```css
#textarea {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 450px;
}
#textarea-show {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #666;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='bold_btn'>B</button>
<button id='italic_btn'>I</button>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable></div>
<div id="textarea-show"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply options on selected text only? tnx

Comment: Yes there is. See my updated answer. You can use `document.execCommand('bold');` for example.

Comment: It works! That is exactly what i need. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it helped you.

Comment: This only works on a button. What if i am not using a button like this: `<span id='bold_btn'> B </span>`

Comment: document.execCommand is deprecated. any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `CSS` `font-style` and `font-weight` to convert your `output text` to **bold** and **italic** as below,

```js
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
  $('#textarea-show').html($(this).text());
});
$(".bld").on('click',function(){
 var a = $('#textarea-show').html($("#textarea").text());
 $(a).css('font-weight','bold');
  $(a).css('font-style','normal');
});

$(".itl").on('click',function(){
 var a = $('#textarea-show').html($("#textarea").text());
 $(a).css('font-style','italic');
 $(a).css('font-weight','normal');
});
```

```css
#textarea { background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 450px;}
    
#textarea-show{font-size: 2rem;
  color:#666;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 450px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="bld">B</button>
<button class="itl">I</button>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable></div>
<div id="textarea-show"></div>
```

**Update** - To make selected text `bold` or `italic` you need to make use of `document.execCommand` as suggested by `@Ionut`,

> When an HTML document has been switched to designMode, the document
>   object exposes the execCommand method which allows one to run commands
>   to manipulate the contents of the editable region.

```js
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
  $('#textarea-show').html($(this).text());
});
$(".bld").on('click',function(){
 document.execCommand('bold');
  var a = $("#textarea").html();
 $('#textarea-show').html(a);
});

$(".itl").on('click',function(){
 document.execCommand('italic');
  var a = $("#textarea").html();
 $('#textarea-show').html(a);
});
```

```css
#textarea { background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 450px;}
    
#textarea-show{font-size: 2rem;
  color:#666;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 450px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="bld">B</button>
<button class="itl">I</button>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable></div>
<div id="textarea-show"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply options on selected text only? tnx

Comment: @17anchi You mean to add bold and italic right, so that's working fine over-here on clicking b or i button which is option to user. Or are you asking something else.

Comment: Ionut found the solution. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @17anchi Welcome :-)